# Определение установки ловушек на события

Tags: jquery

Все мы знаем что можно установить ловушку на событие элемента, в том числе и кастомные.

```
$(selector).on('event', function (){});
```

Как можно определить установку такой ловушки?

Для чего это нужно? Представим некий клиент-контрол, который висит в общем шаблоне и способен принимать запросы от сервера. Для этого ему необходимо установить коннект с этим сервером. Ответы сервера он заворачивает в `trigger()`. Значит можно воспользоваться данным контролом, просто навесившись на его событие. Хочется чтобы подключение к серверу данным контролом осуществлялось только если есть навесившиеся hooks.

Вариант с переопределением метода `on()` не совсем подходит, так как нужно перехватывать только события для элемента, к которому привязан данный контрол.

Answer (score 1):

[Такой метод](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518441/238336) получения привязанных event-ов не поможет? Или [такой](https://github.com/sebastien-p/jquery.hasEventListener)?

Comment: полезные ссылки, близко, но немног не то. Мне надо навеситься на добавление в этот массив.